# Go (Golang) Worker Pool Concurrency Problem: Printing phnno in sendOTP Not Working as Expected

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

Hi there I am simulating a OTP service which sends OTP asynchronously using worker pool pattern

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

var phnno = 0

var queue chan int

func generateOTP() uint16 {
    return 1234
}

func saveToDB(otp uint16, phone uint32) {
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
}

func sendOTP(phnno uint32) {
    otp := generateOTP()
    saveToDB(otp, uint32(phnno))
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) // send request to a sms service provider to send OTP
    fmt.Println(phnno)
}

func waitForPhnno() {
    for phnno := range queue {
        sendOTP(uint32(phnno))
    }
}

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
        go waitForPhnno()
    }

    queue = make(chan int, 10000)
    defer close(queue)

    http.ListenAndServe(":5000", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        phnno++
        select {
        case queue <- phnno:
            w.Write([]byte("email will be sent shortly"))
        default:
            w.Write([]byte("server is currently busy try again later"))
        }
    }))
}
```

But when I make a request I don't see the phnno (in sendOTP func) being printed into server console why its behaving like this ?

Edit: when I reduce the number of worker goroutines (waitForPhonno) to 10, 100 or 1000 the phnno (in sendOTP func) is being printed but doesn't prints for 10000 worker goroutines

Comment: The program has a data race on package-level variable `queue`.  Fix by assigning to `queue` before starting the goroutines.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank You

Comment: There are other data races in the program.  Run the program with the [race detector](https://go.dev/doc/articles/race_detector) an fix the reported problems.